# Are there rules for omitting にin phrases?

Tags: particle-に

> 暗い森、さまよう　"Kurai mori, samayou"

translates to "in the dark forest you wander". Is the comma here replacing the function of ni? can you always replace it this way or is it specific to this sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the comma here replacing the function of ni?

No, it isn't -- in two meanings.

---

First, your phrase "*kurai mori, samayou*" ([暗]{くら}い[森]{もり}、さまよう) is not a grammatically well-formed sentence.

It looks like just saying "Dark forest, (you) wander." How you interpret these words is up to you. So that comma doesn't have the function of *ni*.

---

Secondly, to be a valid sentence, it should be "*kurai mori **o** samayou*" ([暗]{くら}い[森]{もり}**を**さまよう).

"*Kurai mori **ni** samayou*" is incorrect.

Comment: thanks, it's from a japanese song. I guess they take freedom to express wrongly in the songs? or is it some sort of slang?

Comment: Also, I guess gramatical rules have many exceptions, but isnt  one of the "ni" particles functions to show where an action is directed to? like "in" in english?

Comment: Isn't を one of the particles that's generally omissible?

Comment: @Pablo They often go beyond grammar in lyrics, poems etc. Especially, particles are occasionally omitted. Here, it is likely that the を particle is omitted.   The usage of "ni" particle is highly related to verbs.  Just the verb samayou doesn't take the ni particle, like we don't say "enter in the room."

Comment: @Nothingatall that's a good question

Comment: @Nothingatall Yes in informal speech を tends to be omitted, but we don't say that's grammatically correct.